# TextView background all colored

Tags: android

I have dynamically added TextView depending on the number of elements. Here is my pseudo code:

```
FlowLayout.LayoutParams lparams = newFlowLayout.LayoutParams(FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView tv=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tv.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.tagsColor));

tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
tv.setText("#" + (post.getTags().get(i).toString()));
tv.setPadding(20,0,20,0);
```

But when I add background color, the color is set on all text and the padding. I want to know how to fix this.

Here is my current Output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EHK6.png)

Comment: add your current output vs your required output

Comment: i added my output

Comment: and what type of output you want..clear it

Comment: i'm adding             tv.setPadding(20,0,20,0); too
i want padding is displayed in white

Comment: Padding will inset your text, but the background colour will be the same. This is what I would expect to see. Use a margin, or nest the layout, or use a drawable with the attributes you want, etc.

Comment: Don't use `getApplicationContext()` for Views. Use the actual Activity. It is needed to get the correct resources for the current theme.

Comment: I'm inside fragment, and color is changed fine but i want the padding the background stay transparent

Comment: `Padding` is part of the view so the background color will be present there as well. You need to add `margin` in `lParams`.

Answer (score 0):

> Edit:
>   Setting margins should've worked.. if you can't here's a trick, if you need:

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
val gap = "<span style=\"color:blue; background-color:blue;\">gap</span>\n"
val text = Html.fromHtml("#PHP " + gap + "#WEB " + gap + "C# ")
textView.text = text
```

Set color accordingly.

Result:

[image: gap in tags]

If you want to change text color not the background/padding, use this:

```
String tags = post.getTags().get(i).toString();
tv.setText("#" + Html.fromHtml("<font color='#EE0000'>" + tags + "</font>"));
```

instead of `ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.tagsColor)` you can directly paste your color code at `color="#"`

**Or**

you can use `setTextColor()` pointed out by  `@PPartisan`

```
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tagsColor))
```

Comment: There's no need to hardcode colours in this way. Just  use `setTextColor`, or a Color Span

Comment: I don't need to change TextColor, it's Htags thats why i puted # then the rest of the word, i need to change textbackground

Comment: @MondherEssid you've already changed background color, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Padding betwen text in colored too, i want to remove it

Answer (score 0):

`Padding` is part of the View so the background color will be present there as well. You need to add margin/spacing between your TextViews.

I think you are using https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout this lib for the FlowLayout. According to the specs, you can add `app:flChildSpacing="16dp"`.

Or, you can add margin to the layout params.

```
FlowLayout.LayoutParams lparams = newFlowLayout.LayoutParams(FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lParams.setMargins(16, 0, 16, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you but there is no method setMargin in this layout

Answer (score 0):

I think your question needs more clarity about what your requirement is. From what we understood you need background only behind the text and spacing around the textview.

As @Froyo already mentioned in his answer setting `Padding` will cause the background to be applied in the padding space. Therefore in order to add spacing without applying the background you need to add `Margins` instead.

The problem is `FlowLayout` extends a `ViewGroup` so in order to set margins you need to get `MarginLayoutParams` instead of the usual `LayoutParams`. So write your code as shown below:

```
FlowLayout.MarginLayoutParams lparams = new FlowLayout.MarginLayoutParams(FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lparams.setMargins(20, 0, 20, 0);

TextView tv=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tv.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.tagsColor));
//even though getApplicationContext() works I think you should make use of the activity/fragment context instead.
tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
tv.setText("#" + (post.getTags().get(i).toString()));
```

Setting margin won't apply the textview background you are setting, so perhaps this is what you were looking for.  Let us know if this worked or were there some other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are setting the background for whole text. Not for the word inside your text. 
To do this, you have to make a custom Spannable. See my current UI i'm working on.
[image]